# Making 'List of Figures' bold

Tags: table-of-contents

Good day,

I changed the font size of 'List of Figures' using:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\huge}
```

But how can I now make the title 'List of Figures' bold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess

```
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\huge\bfseries}
```

Comment: Cheers, as easy as it gets.